# Any Solutions to fix Type 'NSNotification.Name' has no member 'UITextField' error?

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I recently installed a pod called "NumericKeyboard" and am getting the following errors. Ive been at this for 2 hours now so any help will be appreciated thanks.

**Error #1: Type 'NSNotification.Name' has no member 'UITextField'**

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name.UITextField.textDidChangeNotification, object: self.textView)
```

**Error #2: Type 'NSNotification.Name' has no member 'UITextView'**

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name.UITextView.textDidChangeNotification, object: self.textView)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: UITextView.textDidChangeNotification, 
                              object: self.textView)
```

Comment: It Works. Thank you!